# Solr how to boot solr instance or create core in classic schema mode by default

Tags: solr

Is there a way to boot solr instance with classic schema as default? or create a core with classic schema as default instead of managed-schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a solrconfig.xml with `<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>`, then use that solrconfig as the template when creating new cores. You can provide this configuration when [issuing the `CREATE` command as the `config` parameter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CoreAdmin+API#CoreAdminAPI-CREATE).

You can also [create a Config Set](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Config+Sets) to use the same configuration across many cores. This is useful if you have one set of configuration files that are supposed to be re-used across different time series or other distinct data sets, but where the actual data is structured identically.

Comment: great, config set also seem nice way to avoid having starting from scratch every time you create a core.